# C: int x = k * (x1, x2, x3)?

Tags: c

What exactly is this called in C?

If I have int x = 3 * (4, 5);

I end up with 15.

Can someone give explanation?

Is this a list where the result is just the first number times the last one?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> In the C and C++ programming languages, the comma operator
>   (represented by the token ,) is a binary operator that evaluates its
>   first operand and discards the result, and then evaluates the second
>   operand and returns this value (and type).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator

So, the result of the `(4, 5)` expression will be `5`.

Comment: Note: it doesn't "return" anything.

Comment: @juanchopanza: The strictly correct word is "yield".

Comment: It's also important to note that the comma separating arguments in a function call is not a comma operator.